# Django separate own log from library log?

Tags: python, django

I have django project which print the log such as below.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
.
.
.
.
logger.debug("test")
```

However I am using boto3 library.

so, there are many debugging information on console from boto3 libraru.

I want to check my own log message.

Is there any good method to do this??

my debug setting is like this below.

```
DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[%(server_time)s] %(message)s a',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['django.server'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: You can *silence* the boto messages using something like `logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.INFO)`, and similar for—I think—botocore and urllib. I’d definitely recommend that by default unless you’re debugging boto, which you rarely need to do.

Comment: @deceze thank you it works!!, As you mentioned , I also silence  `logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.INFO)` too